# Is a netflow record equal to a session?

Tags: networking, netflow

Because I don't very understand a session definition in network I have a puzzle that whether a netflow record equal to a session?
If I upload some files to the server through FTP at a time, and there produce 50
netflow records(same source and destination IP but ports are different). Does the process equal to 50 sessions, or the process after the server closed the connection equal to only one session?

such like this photo:
[image]

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer; It all depends.

There are many factors and variables when working with network flows, whether it's Cisco's Netflow format (in various versions), IETF's IPFIX or other similar formats. If we take a very common format, Netflow v5, a flow is defined by 5 or 7 tuples (depending on how detailed the definition is). These tuples are; Source and destination IP address, source and destination port and protocol (in addition Type of Service and ingress interface index). Also Netflow v5 is a uni-directional network flow protocol, meaning it will treat connections coming from the server separately from those going to the server. So any IP packet matching that 5/7 tuple definition in one direction will constitute a network flow and result in a Netflow record. All this have to be taken into consideration when examining Netflow data and comparing it to network communication sessions (which by itself also may have different definitions based on its context).

And as if that wasn't enough, there are also implementation specific variables and limitations, that may split a session into several records. Usually flow protocols implement various timeouts to be able to efficiently collect and store data. TCP sessions may have connections open over a long time period, and makes it challenging for the flow generator to keep and maintain the flow in memory. Some network flow formats have the ability to locate such split records and merge them into one single flow record.

So, to sum up, network analysts starting to work with network flows easily fall into the trap of thinking one record equals one session. That assumption may be true sometimes, but not always.